# newest entry at the top Treelist devexpress vb.net

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

my treelist is getting new row of data using :

```
Dim newNode As TreeListNode = TreeList1.AppendNode(New Object() {"Sold", size, price, startTime.ToShortTimeString()}, -1)
```

I would like the new rows to show on top of the treelist instead of going down after new row, how can I achieve at ?

I tried the following which did not work :

```
TreeList1.OptionsView.NewItemRowPosition = DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeListNewItemRowPosition.Top
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the node to the desired index within its parent via the `TreeList.SetNodeIndex` method. From [How to insert a TreeList node into a specific position](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/a1042/how-to-insert-a-treelist-node-into-a-specific-position):

```
Dim parentNode As TreeListNode = treeList1.Nodes(0)  
' insert a new node as the first child within its parent  
Dim newNode As TreeListNode = treeList1.AppendNode(New Object() {"New first child"}, parentNode)  
treeList1.SetNodeIndex(newNode, 0)
```